# Finding the dimension of the subspace of polynomials which vanish at 2 points

Tags: linear-algebra

I found the following problem in an old course page of my university.

Let $V$ be the (infinite dimensional) vector space of all polynomials
over $\mathbb R $. Let $W$ be the subspace of polynomials of degree $≤ n $ where
$n ≥ 2 $. Also fix distinct points $ a, b ∈ \Bbb R$ and let $U$ be the subspace of
polynomials which vanish at both $a$ and $b$. Determine the dimension of the
subspace $U ∩W$. Give a precise proof for it using only material in Chapter 1.

I approached the problem in the following way, and I just wanted to check if its correct

I tried to show that the set {${ (x-a)(x-b), x(x-a)(x-b),....x^{n-2}(x-a)(x-b)}$} is a basis for the subspace.

Is there any other simpler method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $\Phi: W \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f \mapsto (f(a), f(b))$.

This $\Phi$ is a linear map of rank $2$, and $U \cap W = \ker \Phi$, so by the rank-nullity theorem, we have $$\dim U \cap W = \dim \ker \Phi = \dim W - \text{rank}~ \Phi = n+1-2 = n-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Simpler, but conceptually very similar: as  for any field $K$, and any $a\neq b\in K$, $K[X]$  is a Euclidean domain, one checks easily that $P(X)$ has $a$ and $b$ as roots if and only if $P(X)$ is divisible by $(X-a)(X-b)$. Hence we have a linear isomorphism
\begin{alignat*}{2}
W &\longrightarrow K_{n-2}[X]&&\text{(polynomials of degree }\le n-2),\\
P(X)&\longmapsto \frac{P(X)}{(X-a)(X-b)}.
\end{alignat*}
So $W$ has dimension $n-1$.